# How to use a parameter to change a default value

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, modelbuilder

I'm learning model builder and creating a Transportation model

I'm reading from a truck table with a `cost` field. This field has already a value on database and I can change to a default value (lets say `Cx`) using `field mapping` and everything go very good, the rest of results use the default value `Cx` to calculate cost.

I also can make the table `truck` be requested as a parameter and it also works ok.

But I want to run some simulations so I want the default value `Cx` be requested as parameter as well. Right now I have to enter on the `field mapping` on the model every time I want to change.

**What tool should I use to make the default value on the "field mapping" also a parameter?**

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want to expose the field mapping parameter of a tool as a parameter. Look at the section [exposing tool parameters](http://help.arcgis.com/En/Arcgisdesktop/10.0/Help/index.html#//002w0000007v000000) to see how you expose a parameter of a tool in model builder. Typically only the inputs and outputs are shown (blue/green blobs) so other parameters of a tool are not shown by default.